# global sequence numbering across different for each groups in XSLT 2.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have to generate an xml file where certain grouped elements (documents which group lines) are numbered with a sequence. In turn, these groups belong within another group (by document type). The numbering must be sequential during all the document, regardless of the group.

See the attribute **DocId** in the Documents element in the example output:

**INPUT**

```
<Entries>
    <Entry>
        <UserID>1</UserID>
        <DocNumber>1002</DocNumber>
        <Description>An invoice</Description>
        <Amount>3103.2000</Amount>
        <DocType>INVOICE</DocType>
    </Entry>
    <Entry>
        <UserID>2</UserID>
        <DocNumber>3001</DocNumber>
        <Description>Some receipt</Description>
        <Amount>2352.0000</Amount>
        <DocType>RECEIPT</DocType>
    </Entry>
    <Entry>
        <UserID>1</UserID>
        <DocNumber>1002</DocNumber>
        <Description>An invoice</Description>
        <Amount>2861.8400</Amount>
        <DocType>INVOICE</DocType>
    </Entry>
    <Entry>
        <UserID>2</UserID>
        <DocNumber>3001</DocNumber>
        <Description>Some receipt</Description>
        <Amount>2352.0000</Amount>
        <DocType>RECEIPT</DocType>
    </Entry>
    <Entry>
        <UserID>5</UserID>
        <DocNumber>1004</DocNumber>
        <Description>Another invoice</Description>
        <Amount>2.34</Amount>
        <DocType>INVOICE</DocType>
    </Entry>
</Entries>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet exclude-result-prefixes="xs xdt err fn" version="2.0" xmlns:err="http://www.w3.org/2005/xqt-errors" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:xdt="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-datatypes" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ser="http://webservice">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>
    <xsl:template match="/Entries">
        <ser:Request>
                <xsl:for-each-group select="Entry" group-by="DocType">
                    <xsl:sort select="current-grouping-key()"/>                    
                    <ser:ItemFile ImportName="{DocType}" Date="{current-date()}">
                        <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="DocNumber">
                            <xsl:sort select="current-grouping-key()"/>                            
                            <ser:Documents DocId="{position()}" DocRef="{DocNumber}" Desc="{Description}" >
                                <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                                    <Line amount="{Amount}"/>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                            </ser:Documents>
                        </xsl:for-each-group>
                    </ser:ItemFile>
                </xsl:for-each-group>
        </ser:Request>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**OUTPUT**

```
<ser:Request xmlns:ser="http://webservice">
   <ser:ItemFile ImportName="INVOICE" Date="2017-10-13+02:00">
      <ser:Documents DocId="1" DocRef="1002" Desc="An invoice">
         <Line amount="3103.2000"/>
         <Line amount="2861.8400"/>
      </ser:Documents>
      <ser:Documents DocId="2" DocRef="1004" Desc="Another invoice">
         <Line amount="2.34"/>
      </ser:Documents>
   </ser:ItemFile>
   <ser:ItemFile ImportName="RECEIPT" Date="2017-10-13+02:00">
      <ser:Documents DocId="1" DocRef="3001" Desc="Some receipt">
         <Line amount="2352.0000"/>
         <Line amount="2352.0000"/>
      </ser:Documents>
   </ser:ItemFile>
</ser:Request>
```

In this example, the desired output for last DocId attribute would be 3, following the sequence.

I noticed if I use the position() function, the numbering restarts in each group, which is not what I want. I also tried the xsl:number element with no success. I considered counting the elements in the first group and adding it to position(), which worked for me for a limited number of groups, but couldn't do it generically for a variable number of groups.

Is there some relatively simple way of achieving this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would store the newly created elements in a variable and then push it through templates that copy everything but that `DocId` attribute where you can then use `xsl:number` to set it:

```
<xsl:stylesheet exclude-result-prefixes="xs xdt err fn" version="2.0" xmlns:err="http://www.w3.org/2005/xqt-errors" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:xdt="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-datatypes" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ser="http://webservice">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/> 

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>  
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/Entries">
        <ser:Request>
            <xsl:variable name="result">
                 <xsl:for-each-group select="Entry" group-by="DocType">
                    <xsl:sort select="current-grouping-key()"/>                    
                    <ser:ItemFile ImportName="{DocType}" Date="{current-date()}">
                        <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="DocNumber">
                            <xsl:sort select="current-grouping-key()"/>                            
                            <ser:Documents DocId="" DocRef="{DocNumber}" Desc="{Description}" >
                                <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                                    <Line amount="{Amount}"/>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                            </ser:Documents>
                        </xsl:for-each-group>
                    </ser:ItemFile>
                </xsl:for-each-group>           
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$result"/>
        </ser:Request>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ser:Documents/@DocId">
        <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
            <xsl:number select=".." level="any"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```